# Adwhirl ads not showing

Tags: android, admob, adwhirl

I have an Android app, and I'm using Adwhirl with Admob and ZestADZ, and I've set up a House ad.

For some reason the ads are not showing, in spite of the log looking normal. All I can see is that the Zest ads are not shown and it should default to House ads I create.

Thanks in advance!

Here is part of my XML:

```
LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/LayoutTopAds"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:background="@color/graphite"
android:layout_weight="0.5"
```

Here is the code:

```
    LinearLayout adLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LayoutTopAds);
    AdWhirlLayout adWhirlLayout = new AdWhirlLayout(this, LearningLangConsts.ADWHIRL_SDK_KEY[myUI.LEARNLANG]);

    int diWidth = adLayout.getWidth();
    int diHeight = adLayout.getHeight();
    float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

    adWhirlLayout.setAdWhirlInterface(new AdWhirlLayout.AdWhirlInterface()
    {
        @Override
        public void adWhirlGeneric()
        {}
    });

    adWhirlLayout.setMaxWidth((int)(diWidth * density));
    adWhirlLayout.setMaxHeight((int)(diHeight * density));
    adLayout.addView(adWhirlLayout);
```

Here is the log:

```
      07-02 16:36:56.791: INFO/AdWhirl SDK(3581): Creating adWhirlManager...
      07-02 16:36:56.851: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(3581): Locale is: en_US
      07-02 16:36:57.354: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(3581): Hashed device ID is: 7d1dd13a2fa91c0ad174cb69a11549a3
      07-02 16:36:57.360: INFO/AdWhirl SDK(3581): Finished creating adWhirlManager
      07-02 16:36:58.140: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(3581): Prefs{73dd1111860847ecb1257a0e0942ec37}: {"config": "{"extra":{"location_on":1,"background_color_rgb":{"red":255,"green":255,"blue":255,"alpha":1},"text_color_rgb":{"red":0,"green":0,"blue":0,"alpha":1},"cycle_time":15,"transition":8},"rations":[{"nid":"7f5ef65976504f21b9635ab0ec19a019","type":1,"nname":"admob","weight":33,"priority":3,"key":"a14123cc7d16913"},{"nid":"49ac21c2a998e168ae8974078a302c0b","type":20,"nname":"zestadz","weight":33,"priority":1,"key":"14131C047A5040548959435145554B5F8D8A29CA"},{"nid":"e7eff2754b0b4bde81114881e88dd8f1","type":9,"nname":"custom","weight":34,"priority":2,"key":"__CUSTOM__"},{"nid":"8c1200a3a29d41c0b9fd16096368d6dc","type":9,"nname":"custom","weight":0,"priority":2,"key":"__CUSTOM__"}]}
      07-02 16:36:58.140: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(3581): ", "timestamp": 1309645632265}
      07-02 16:36:58.150: INFO/AdWhirl SDK(3581): Using stored config data
      07-02 16:36:58.181: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(3581): Received jsonString: {"extra":{"location_on":1,"background_color_rgb":{"red":255,"green":255,"blue":255,"alpha":1},"text_color_rgb":{"red":0,"green":0,"blue":0,"alpha":1},"cycle_time":15,"transition":8},"rations":[{"nid":"7f5ef65926c44f21b9635ab0e122a019","type":1,"nname":"admob","weight":33,"priority":3,"key":"a14e0dcc7d16913"},{"nid":"49ac243ae94c4f68ae8974078a302c0b","type":20,"nname":"zestadz","weight":33,"priority":1,"key":"14131C047A504052787735145554B5F8D8A29CA"},{"nid":"e7eff27c4b0b4bd3222db881e88dd8f1","type":9,"nname":"custom","weight":34,"priority":2,"key":"__CUSTOM__"},{"nid":"8c1200a3a29d41c0b9fd16834423d6dc","type":9,"nname":"custom","weight":0,"priority":2,"key":"__CUSTOM__"}]}
      07-02 16:36:59.953: INFO/AdWhirl SDK(3581): Rotating Ad
      07-02 16:37:00.080: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(3581): Dart is <8.98131054165815> of <100.0>
      07-02 16:37:01.890: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(3581): Showing ad:
      07-02 16:37:01.890: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(3581):     nid: 49ac21c2a94c4f68154434078a302c0b
      07-02 16:37:01.890: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(3581):     name: zestadz
      07-02 16:37:01.890: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(3581):     type: 20
      07-02 16:37:01.890: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(3581):     key: 14349877A5040434E59435145554B5F8D8A29CA
      07-02 16:37:01.890: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(3581):     key2: 
      07-02 16:37:01.943: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(3581): Valid adapter, calling handle()
      07-02 16:37:01.970: INFO/ZestADZ SDK(3581): Adclient ID set to 14131C047A5040434E59435145554B5F8D8A29CA
      07-02 16:37:04.730: VERBOSE/Formed URL(3581): http://a.zestadz.com/waphandler/deliverad?ua=Mozilla%2F5.0+%28Linux%3B+U%3B+Android+2.1-update1%3B+en-us%3B+sdk+Build%2FECLAIR%29+AppleWebKit%2F530.17+%28KHTML%2C+like+Gecko%29+Version%2F4.0+Mobile+Safari%2F530.17&ip=&cid=14131C047A504342216435145554B5F8D8A29CA&meta=game&keyword=All
      07-02 16:37:09.921: DEBUG/Ad Response(3581): HTTP/1.1 200 OK
      07-02 16:37:10.040: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(3581): ZestADZ failure
      07-02 16:37:10.351: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(3581): Showing ad:
      07-02 16:37:10.351: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(3581):     nid: 49ac21c2a94c4f68ae835645987302c0b
      07-02 16:37:10.351: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(3581):     name: zestadz
      07-02 16:37:10.351: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(3581):     type: 20
      07-02 16:37:10.351: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(3581):     key: 14131234487040434E59435145554B5F8D8A29CA
      07-02 16:37:10.351: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(3581):     key2: 
      07-02 16:37:10.372: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(3581): Valid adapter, calling handle()
      07-02 16:37:10.400: INFO/ZestADZ SDK(3581): Adclient ID set to 14131C047A5040434E59435640954B5F8D8A29CA
      07-02 16:37:11.432: VERBOSE/Formed URL(3581): http://a.zestadz.com/waphandler/deliverad?ua=Mozilla%2F5.0+%28Linux%3B+U%3B+Android+2.1-update1%3B+en-us%3B+sdk+Build%2FECLAIR%29+AppleWebKit%2F530.17+%28KHTML%2C+like+Gecko%29+Version%2F4.0+Mobile+Safari%2F530.17&ip=&cid=14131C047A501233329435145554B5F8D8A29CA&meta=game&keyword=All
      07-02 16:37:13.060: DEBUG/Ad Response(3581): HTTP/1.1 200 OK
      07-02 16:37:13.190: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(3581): ZestADZ failure
      07-02 16:37:13.530: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(3581): Showing ad:
      07-02 16:37:13.530: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(3581):     nid: e7eff27c4b0b4bd455223381e88dd8f1
      07-02 16:37:13.530: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(3581):     name: custom
      07-02 16:37:13.530: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(3581):     type: 9
      07-02 16:37:13.530: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(3581):     key: __CUSTOM__
      07-02 16:37:13.530: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(3581):     key2: 
      07-02 16:37:13.550: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(3581): Valid adapter, calling handle()
      07-02 16:37:13.670: DEBUG/LocationManager(3581): Constructor: service = android.location.ILocationManager$Stub$Proxy@43baf168
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you set your `LinearLayout` height to `0dp`: `android:layout_height="0dp"`
This would cause your View to not show. Try changing it to `wrap_content` instead. If that doesn't work there is actually an easier way to create the AdWhirl layout:

I'm assuming you have version 3.0 of the AdWhirl SDK. Instead of creating the layout through code you can simply create it through your normal XML layout file. Don't use the `LinearLayout` like their instructions suggest (I think it's outdated). Instead just place this element in your layout wherever you want the banner to be:

```
    <com.adwhirl.AdWhirlLayout
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Seriously, that's it. Be sure your AdWhirl key is in the Manifest as well (either within the `<activity>` or `<application>` tag):

```
    <meta-data android:value="Your Key"
         android:name="ADWHIRL_KEY"/>
```

If you really need to do anything programmatically you can give the layout an `id` as usual and use `findViewById`. Lemme know if this helps.